# Bringing a permutation back to the identity

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm working with transposition distance (nothing to do with algebraic transpositions) on given permutations. Given a permutation, how many moves (transpositions) will it take to get back to the identity. A transposition exchanges consecutive strings in a permutation. For example, consider the following permutation:

$$(\begin{matrix}\underline{3} & \underline{2 \ \ \ \ 1} & 5 & 4\end{matrix}) \rightarrow
(\begin{matrix} \underline{2} & \underline{1} & 3 & 5 & 4\end{matrix}) \rightarrow
(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & \underline{5} & \underline{4}\end{matrix}) \rightarrow
(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\end{matrix}).$$

It takes a minimum of 3 moves to return it to the identity, so we say it has transposition distance 3. Now, what is the transposition distance of the following permutation:

$$(\begin{matrix} 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\end{matrix})?$$

I say it has transposition distance 4, but my book (Combinatorics of Genome Rearrangements) says that no permutations of length 5 have t.d. 4. Can anyone find a way to bring that permutation back to the identity in no more than 3 moves?

Comment: I don't understand your first step above. It looks like you applied a cycle of order $3$, not a transposition.

Comment: My use of the word "transposition" is not the same that is used in abstract algebra. It refers to biological transpositions.

Comment: Okay, in that case I don't understand which moves are permitted and which aren't. Can you explain?

Comment: You may switch any two consecutive strings of numbers. I can give you a formal definition, but it would be lengthy and more confusing.

Comment: Notice in the first step, the string "3" is switched with the consecutive string "2 1".

Comment: So if you have an arrangement $ABCD$, where $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are blocks of numbers (possibly empty in the case of $A$ and $D$), you can move to $ACBD$, and that is the only thing you can do in one turn. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite. You can switch any blocks that are touching each other. Assuming you don't group two blocks together (which you could), the only illegal moves would be switching A with C, A with D, and B with D.

Comment: The only reason why the only legal move would be ACBD is if both A and D were empty.

Comment: That's not really what I meant. What I meant is that for any legal move, it's possible to break the arrangement into blocks $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ so that the move is described by $ABCD \mapsto ACBD$. For example, for $43512687 \mapsto 43568712$, we'd have $A = 435$, $B = 12$, $C = 687$ and $D$ empty.

Comment: Sure, that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halfway through a meet-in-the-middle brute force search, I found:

$$ \underline{5~4}~\underline{3~2}~1 \to 3~\underline{2~5}~\underline{4~1}
\to \underline{3~4}~\underline{1~2}~5 \to 1~2~3~4~5 $$

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!